# PowershellでDiagnostics.ProcessのBeginOutputReadLineを実行するとアプリケーションがハングアップする

Tags: .net, powershell

お世話になります。

掲題の件で原因が分からずに困っております。

BeginOutputReadLineの実行直後に、呼び出し元のPowershell.exe（またはPowershell_ise.exe）が
ハングアップしてしまう事象が発生しております。非同期ではなく、
同期による標準出力の読み取りでは問題無いのですが、標準エラーも扱いたいため、
少なくとも一方を非同期で読み取らせる様にしたいのです。

この問題に関する解決策や、何かしら解決につながるヒントをいただければと存じます。

■当方環境
Windows 10 32bit
Powershell v5.1
.Net Framework 4.7.2

■テストソース

```
Using Namespace System.Diagnostics
Using Namespace System.Text
Using Namespace System.Windows.Forms

Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms

$args = "-Command `"& {Get-Date}`""
$passwd = [System.Security.SecureString]::new()
"qwerty123".ToCharArray() | %{$passwd.AppendChar($_)}
$StartInfo = [ProcessStartInfo]::new('Powershell.exe', $args)
$StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$StartInfo.UserName = $env:USERNAME
$StartInfo.Password = $passwd
$StartInfo.Domain = $env:USERDOMAIN
$StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = $true
$StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = $env:HOMEPATH
$p = [Process]::new()
$p.StartInfo = $StartInfo
$p.Start()
$stdout = [StringBuilder]::new()
$p.add_OutputDataReceived( {
    param( $p, $e )
    $stdout.AppendLine( $e.Data )
} )
$p.BeginOutputReadLine()

[MessageBox]::Show($stdout.ToString(), "test")
```

【追記】
また、以下の様にイベントログに記録されています。

障害バケット 1454065438036662408、
種類 5 
イベント名: PowerShell 
応答: 使用不可 
Cab ID: 0 
問題の署名: 
P1: powershell_ise.exe 
P2: 10.0.18362.752 
P3: Management.Automation.PSInvalidOperation 
P4: Management.Automation.PSInvalidOperation 
P5: anagement.Automation.ScriptBlock.GetContextFromTLS P6: anagement.Automation.ScriptBlock.GetContextFromTLS P7: unknown P8: P9: P10:

Comment: 確認ですが、ユーザー・パスワード・ドメインがしていされているのは、最終的には別権限での実行を目指しているからでしょうか？ それとも標準出力と標準エラー出力の両方が扱えれば手段は問わないのでしょうか？ あと、イベントログの内容は私の回答を元に修正したコードに対するものであり、質問文記載のコードによるものではないので、質問文としては対応がとれていないと思います。

Comment: sayuriさん ユーザー・パスワード・ドメインはセキュリティの観点から指定した方が良いかなという思い付きで、マストではなく、ご指摘の通り標準入出力が同時に扱えることが要件となります。また、イベントログにつきましては、質問に掲載したテストコードでも、sayuriさんにご提示頂きましたコードでも全く同じ内容が出力されております。この点説明が不足しており申し訳ございません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

指摘事項が多数あるため、再度整理します。

- [`Process.OutputDataReceived`イベントの例](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived?view=netframework-4.7.2#-)を見ると`$p.Start()`よりも前にイベントを登録しています。順序を入れ替えてください。
- [`add_OutputDataReceived`はダメ](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12338)でPowerShell v5.1では修正予定がないそうです。[`Register-ObjectEvent`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent?view=powershell-5.1)を使う必要があります。
- `Register-ObjectEvent`で登録したイベントはきちんと[`Unregister-Event`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unregister-event?view=powershell-5.1)で解除する必要があります。
- `Unregister-Event`でイベント解除する前に[`Process.WaitForExit`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netframework-4.7.2)でプロセスの終了を待つ必要があります。

あといくつか推奨事項も

- パスワードを指定することがセキュリティを高めることではありません。同じ権限を引き継ぐだけであれば、指定すべきではありません。
- `RedirectStandardOutput = $true`が期待する動作かと思います。

はどうでしょうか？

```
$args = "Get-Date"
$stdout = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()

$p = [System.Diagnostics.Process]@{
    StartInfo = @{
        FileName = 'Powershell.exe'
        Arguments = $args
        RedirectStandardOutput = $true
        UseShellExecute = $false
        WorkingDirectory = $env:HOMEPATH
    }
}
$ev = Register-ObjectEvent $p -EventName OutputDataReceived -MessageData $stdout -Action {
     $Event.MessageData.AppendLine($Event.SourceEventArgs.Data)
}
$p.Start()
$p.BeginOutputReadLine()
$p.WaitForExit()
Unregister-Event $ev.Id

[MessageBox]::Show($stdout.ToString(), "test")
```

---

身もふたもないですが、標準出力と標準エラー出力を混ぜてもよいならこれだけでできます。

```
$args = "Get-Date"
& powershell.exe $args 2>&1 | Set-Variable stdout

[MessageBox]::Show($stdout, "test")
```

Comment: sayuriさん  
ご提案ありがとうございます。  
仰る通りに致しましたが状況は変わりませんでした。  
  
なお、イベントログで以下の通りNull参照が発生している様なのですが、何がNullになっているのか調査する方法はあるのでしょうか…  
  
引き続きどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。  
  
障害バケット 、種類 0  
イベント名: PowerShell  
応答: 使用不可  
Cab ID: 0  

問題の署名:  
P1: Powershell.exe  
P2: 10.0.18362.752  
P3: System.NullReferenceException  
P4: System.NullReferenceException  
P5: unknown  
P6: PlatformWindows.OnBreak  
P7: unknown  
P8: 
P9: 
P10: 
  
添付ファイル:
  
これらのファイルは次の場所にある可能性があります:
  
分析記号: 
解決策を再確認中: 0
レポート ID: 8d6c589b-0d3e-4f77-ab2a-42d159b16ed4
レポートの状態: 268697600
ハッシュされたバケット: 
Cab GUID: 0

Comment: 連投ごめんなさい。Null参照はちょっとした手違い（$argsはPowershell予約変数でしたので$argumentsに変えました…）だったため再度手違い修正してやり直したところ、以下の通りのエラーレポートが出力されております。

障害バケット 1454065438036662408、種類 5
イベント名: PowerShell
応答: 使用不可
Cab ID: 0

問題の署名:
P1: powershell_ise.exe
P2: 10.0.18362.752
P3: Management.Automation.PSInvalidOperation
P4: Management.Automation.PSInvalidOperation
P5: anagement.Automation.ScriptBlock.GetContextFromTLS
P6: anagement.Automation.ScriptBlock.GetContextFromTLS
P7: unknown
P8: 
P9: 
P10: 

添付ファイル:

～文字数制限のため後略～

Comment: @Koichiro そのエラーを質問文に記載すればいいのでは？

Comment: sayuriさん。ありがとうございます。そのように致します。

Comment: その後出力バッファによるデッドロック問題に取り掛かっていたためお返事遅くなりすみません。無事解決致しました。誠にありがとうございました。